# Paypal integration controller not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

I create an account at paypal to test in my app.

```
 composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php
```

Added the client ID and secret to the .env

This is what I currently have in my view

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="w3-panel w3-green w3-display-container">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
                class="w3-button w3-green w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <p>{!! $message !!}</p>
    </div>
    <?php Session::forget('success');?>
    @endif
@if ($message = Session::get('error'))
    <div class="w3-panel w3-red w3-display-container">
        <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
                class="w3-button w3-red w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <p>{!! $message !!}</p>
    </div>
    <?php Session::forget('error');?>
    @endif
<form class="w3-container w3-display-middle w3-card-4 " method="POST" id="payment-form"  action="{!! URL::to('paypal') !!}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h2 class="w3-text-blue">Payment Form</h2>
    <p>      
    <label class="w3-text-blue"><b>Enter Amount</b></label>
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="amount" type="text"></p>      
    <button class="w3-btn w3-blue">Pay with PayPal</button></p>
</form>
```

My PaymentController looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\ChargeModel;
use PayPal\Api\Currency;
use PayPal\Api\MerchantPreferences;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentDefinition;
use PayPal\Api\Plan;
use PayPal\Api\Patch;
use PayPal\Api\PatchRequest;
use PayPal\Common\PayPalModel;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

use URL;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    private $apiContext;
    private $mode;
    private $client_id;
    private $secret;

    public function __construct()
        {
    /** PayPal api context **/
            $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
            $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $paypal_conf['client_id'],
                $paypal_conf['secret'])
            );
            $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }

    public function payWithpaypal(Request $request){
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
                ->setCurrency('USD')
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setPrice($request->get('amount')); /** unit price **/
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
                ->setTotal($request->get('amount'));
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                ->setItemList($item_list)
                ->setDescription('Your transaction description');
        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('status')) /** Specify return URL **/
                ->setCancelUrl(URL::route('status'));
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
                ->setPayer($payer)
                ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
                ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
            /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; **/

        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
            \Session::put('error', 'Connection timeout');
                            return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
            } else {
            \Session::put('error', 'Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
                            return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
            }
        }
        foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
        $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                        break;
        }
        }
        /** add payment ID to session **/
                Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
        if (isset($redirect_url)) {
        /** redirect to paypal **/
                    return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }
        \Session::put('error', 'Unknown error occurred');
                return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus(){
        /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
        $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
/** clear the session payment ID **/
        Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
        if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
            \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
            return Redirect::route('/');
        }
        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));
        /**Execute the payment **/
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {

            /*************************************************
                PAYMENT SUCCESSFULL - DO THE REST HERE
            /************************************************/

            \Session::put('success', 'Payment success');
            return Redirect::route('/');
        }
        \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
                return Redirect::route('/');
    }
}
```

So now when I enter an amount and try to pay, I get the following error:

```
 Argument 1 passed to PayPal\Rest\ApiContext::setConfig() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\owlproperty\app\Http\Controllers\PaymentController.php on line 47
```

I created the paypal file under the config folder and that looks like this:

```
<?php 
return [ 
    'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID',''),
    'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SECRET',''),
    'settings' => array(
        'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE','sandbox'),
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'
    ),
];
```

Anything I could have possibly done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the config file correctly:

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration):

> The configuration values may be accessed using "dot" syntax, which
>   includes the name of    the file and option you wish to access.

Assuming your confile file is named paypal.php, use this in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
        /** PayPal api context **/
        $settings  = config('paypal.settings');
        $client_id = config('paypal.client_id');
        $secret    = config('paypal.secret');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
           $client_id,
           $secret)
        );
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($settings);
}
```

Comment: Still shows the same error. I do not quite understand because I used the exact same code in another test app

Comment: I just tied your code and still see exactly the same error.

Comment: I updated the code to use the global helper function, just in case. Also, are you sure about the config's file path and filename?

Comment: do not quite follow. Which file name?
Inside the paypal.php I have the code as it is above in my question.
Then in the .env I have the client_id and secret

Comment: If the config is in yourproject/config/paypal.php , then this should work